# Browserify gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

I have tried installing npm browserify globally with a command `npm i -g browserify`. Then I wrote in terminal `browserify app.js -o bundle.js` command, which created bundle.js file, and then I went to my index.html and I changed my script to `<script defer src="bundle.js"/>` . I went to check and indeed error Uncaught referenceError: require is not defined is gone, but I have this new error:

```
bundle.js:41149 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:41149)
    at Object.236../utils (bundle.js:42251)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at Object.232../application (bundle.js:40389)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at Object.230../lib/express (bundle.js:39717)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:41149
236../utils @ bundle.js:42251
o @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:1
232../application @ bundle.js:40389
o @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:1
230../lib/express @ bundle.js:39717
o @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:36124
206._process @ bundle.js:36133
o @ bundle.js:1
r @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:1
```

Comment: Can you post your code also.

Comment: @PawanKumar I posted answer down

Answer (score 0):

This is my app.js file, index html has nothing in it. And bundle.js has like 60k lines of code, I can't show it.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5500;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: html is just baysic layout with nothing and `<script defer src="bundle.js"/>`

Comment: I can see the same error. This error is due to absence of ```ServerResponse``` field for ```http``` object.

Comment: @PawanKumar how do I fix it

Comment: May I know why do you want to browserify the Web server application. And most of the functions wont work because of security purposes. From Browser you cannot touch File system.

Comment: @PawanKumar I want to connect my app.js and my html, so when I call server on port ... I can  use express etc. Trying to make a site with js,nodejs,css and html. Not react or smth. I need require tho

Comment: Don't use browserify, Use ES6 Imports use Babel to transpile ES6 imports and no one want to run their server code to run on browser. The code you posted must be running on a Web server. But you are trying to run it on a Browser, which wont work and is not even considered safe.